# ICEFaces 1.8.2 and IBM WebSphere Application Server 8?

Tags: jsf, websphere, icefaces

I have upgraded my WebSphere Application Server from version 6.1 to 8.0, but my application does not work anymore and gives the following error.  It uses ICEFaces 1.8.2 and JSF 1.1.  It seems to be missing the class BridgeFacesContext2, but never had problems with it before in WAS 6.1.

```
[5/17/12 16:43:20:552 EDT] 00000026 MainServlet   I com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainServlet setUpCoreMessageService Blocking Request Handler: "auto-detect"
[5/17/12 16:43:20:802 EDT] 00000026 EnvironmentAd I com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.EnvironmentAdaptingServlet <init> Adapting to Thread Blocking environment
[5/17/12 16:43:23:334 EDT] 00000026 MainServlet   W com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainServlet setUpCoreMessageService Push Server not found - the Push Server must be deployed to support multiple asynchronous applications.
[5/17/12 16:43:23:334 EDT] 00000026 MainServlet   I com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainServlet setUpCoreMessageService Adapting to Push environment.
[5/17/12 16:43:23:459 EDT] 00000026 AssociatedPag I com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.portlet.page.AssociatedPageViewsImpl getImplementation using com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.portlet.page.NoOpAssociatedPageViews
[5/17/12 16:43:23:678 EDT] 00000026 View          E com.icesoft.faces.context.View servePage Problem encountered during View.servePage 
                             java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.icefaces.x.context.BridgeFacesContext2
at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:132)
at com.icesoft.faces.context.View$2.serve(View.java:68)
at com.icesoft.faces.context.View.servePage(View.java:149)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.MultiViewServer.service(MultiViewServer.java:67)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.common.ServerProxy.service(ServerProxy.java:11)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainSessionBoundServlet$4.service(MainSessionBoundServlet.java:149)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.common.standard.PathDispatcherServer.service(PathDispatcherServer.java:24)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.BasicAdaptingServlet.service(BasicAdaptingServlet.java:16)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher.service(PathDispatcher.java:23)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.SessionDispatcher.service(SessionDispatcher.java:53)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher.service(PathDispatcher.java:23)
at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:131)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1147)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:722)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:449)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1020)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1382)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:191)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:648)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1020)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3639)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:950)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1659)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:276)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1648)
```

I was looking through icefaces.jar and noticed that there is a BridgeFacesContext.class in icefaces.jar\com\icesoft\faces\context.  Not sure if this is the same class that it can't find.

I have tried different versions of WebSphere's built-in JSF jars (after seeing [this](http://jforum.icesoft.org/JForum/posts/list/20359.page)), but no luck.  Does anyone know how to configure ICEFaces 1.8.2 to work with WAS 8?

Do I need to upgrade to ICEFaces 3?  If so, is the open-source version compatible with WAS 8?  (WAS 8 seems to be only listed under the EE version [here](http://www.icesoft.org/projects/ICEfaces/supported-platforms.jsf))

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Our official support for WebSphere is as follows:

WebSphere 6, 7, and 8 are supported by our ICEfaces 1.8 EE product running on JSF 1.2.
WebSphere 7 and 8 are supported by our ICEfaces 3.0 EE product running on JSF 2.1

Support for WebSphere 8 was recently added in the latest 1.8 EE release:

http://res.icesoft.org/releasenotes/icefacesEE-1.8.2.GA_P04-RN.html#Supported_Platforms

So in your situation, an upgrade to ICEfaces EE 1.8 or ICEfaces EE 3.0 (recommended) would be the required course of action.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Deryk.  Will the open-source version of IceFaces ever support WAS 8?

Comment: In general, our guideline is that we don't provide support for non-open source servers in our own open source product.

Comment: Okay, thank you Deryk.  I was just wondering why WAS 6 and 7 are supported in the open-source version, but not WAS 8.  I understand that it is only a year old, but it would be easier for people who want to upgrade their servers if the ICEfaces 3.0 open-source version supported it as well since older WAS versions are supported.